# PowerShell not displaying Unix colors

Tags: linux, colors, powershell, console

I use various Linux programs on my Windows machine; some of them have colorized output. GnuWin32 and so forth.

However, Windows PowerShell does not support Linux colors; it gets a message like `←[0m31m`(which is the color control code), and renders that instead of the color.

Is there any way around this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Powershell is just a text-mode program, running in the Windows console.  The Windows console does not support [ANSI escape sequences](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI%5Fescape%5Fcode) which is what you are seeing.

To fix it, it depends a lot on which program you are using.  I am guessing you use cygwin to run these scripts?

Comment: In this instance, I was using a python program, mercurial.

Comment: I wish you had said Perl, then I would tell you about the Win32::Console module for Perl :)  I am not sure what you can do to get colors with Windows-Python.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [Cygwin](http://cygwin.org) to run PowerShell and PowerShell scripts:

[image]

Cygwin can handle the escape sequences.

Comment: What if I don't want to use cygwin?

Comment: Then you can take any of the other suggestions here

Answer (score 3):

**For posterity**

You can use [ANSICON](https://github.com/adoxa/ansicon/) to display ANSI escape sequences in Windows consoles, including Powershell.  This should give you color.

This [issue thread on getting it to work with PowerShell](https://github.com/adoxa/ansicon/issues/13) has a few different solutions as there is more than one way to do it.

Answer (score 3):

I was also searching for a good solution, but I couldn't find any ...

Here is a short PowerShell script to translate ANSI color codes:

```
function Open-Colored([String] $Filename)
  { Write-Colored(cat -Raw $Filename) }

function Write-Colored([String] $text)
  { # split text at ESC-char
    $split = $text.Split([char] 27)
    foreach ($line in $split)
      { if ($line[0] -ne '[')
          { Write-Host $line -NoNewline }
        else
          { if     (($line[1] -eq '0') -and ($line[2] -eq 'm')) { Write-Host $line.Substring(3) -NoNewline }
            elseif (($line[1] -eq '3') -and ($line[3] -eq 'm'))
              { # normal color codes
                if     ($line[2] -eq '0') { Write-Host $line.Substring(4) -NoNewline -ForegroundColor Black       }
                elseif ($line[2] -eq '1') { Write-Host $line.Substring(4) -NoNewline -ForegroundColor DarkRed     }
                elseif ($line[2] -eq '2') { Write-Host $line.Substring(4) -NoNewline -ForegroundColor DarkGreen   }
                elseif ($line[2] -eq '3') { Write-Host $line.Substring(4) -NoNewline -ForegroundColor DarkYellow  }
                elseif ($line[2] -eq '4') { Write-Host $line.Substring(4) -NoNewline -ForegroundColor DarkBlue    }
                elseif ($line[2] -eq '5') { Write-Host $line.Substring(4) -NoNewline -ForegroundColor DarkMagenta }
                elseif ($line[2] -eq '6') { Write-Host $line.Substring(4) -NoNewline -ForegroundColor DarkCyan    }
                elseif ($line[2] -eq '7') { Write-Host $line.Substring(4) -NoNewline -ForegroundColor Gray        }
              }
            elseif (($line[1] -eq '3') -and ($line[3] -eq ';') -and ($line[5] -eq 'm'))
              { # bright color codes
                if     ($line[2] -eq '0') { Write-Host $line.Substring(6) -NoNewline -ForegroundColor DarkGray    }
                elseif ($line[2] -eq '1') { Write-Host $line.Substring(6) -NoNewline -ForegroundColor Red         }
                elseif ($line[2] -eq '2') { Write-Host $line.Substring(6) -NoNewline -ForegroundColor Gree        }
                elseif ($line[2] -eq '3') { Write-Host $line.Substring(6) -NoNewline -ForegroundColor Yellow      }
                elseif ($line[2] -eq '4') { Write-Host $line.Substring(6) -NoNewline -ForegroundColor Blue        }
                elseif ($line[2] -eq '5') { Write-Host $line.Substring(6) -NoNewline -ForegroundColor Magenta     }
                elseif ($line[2] -eq '6') { Write-Host $line.Substring(6) -NoNewline -ForegroundColor Cyan        }
                elseif ($line[2] -eq '7') { Write-Host $line.Substring(6) -NoNewline -ForegroundColor White       }
              }
          }
      }
  }
```

Usage:

```
Open-Colored .\myColoredLogfile.log
```

Currently, I have no idea how to integrate this into a pages (e.g. less) or how to write a own simple pager like less.

[PSCX](http://pscx.codeplex.com/) comes with a less clone, but it has no ANSI color code support (yet)...

Answer (score 0):

You could use a Linux virtual machine to launch these scripts. This is a big thing for a small result if it's just about showing colors, but it can't hurt to run the scripts on the platform they were made for.

Comment: yeah, that's too big to justify for this one thing. Plus I don't have a VM hypervisor running, and I do *not* want to install one.

Answer (score 0):

You said you were using Mercurial to run the Linux programs.  Assuming you're referring to the source control system (which I didn't realize could run Linux programs; I only use it for source control), there's an extension that will let you show color.  [Wincolor](http://bitbucket.org/sborho/wincolor/) will intercept the ANSI color control and call the appropriate Windows functions.  It seems to work no matter what, but I think it works better with [pyreadline](http://ipython.scipy.org/Wiki/PyReadline/Intro) installed.

Note: I have treid this without pyreadline, and it didn't work for me.  I have not yet tried it with pyreadline.